# how to use two column in different table and use between operator. in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two table say A and B in Hive. table A has "position" column and table B has  "startposition" and "endposition" column. I am trying to do  something like .

```
select * from A where position between (select startposition from B) AND (select endposition from B);
```

But it is not working and given exception . 
how could we do that so each position of table A is check against each pair of  startposition and endposition of table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
     position 
from A 
    join B 
where 
A.position > B.startposition AND A.position<B.endposition;
```

[LanguageManual Joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)